# Php script is not working properly in browser

Tags: php, python, browser, nginx

if i make change like bellow my php script is working fine in browser

```
<?php
&cmd = system('python script.py /home/user/filename.zip /home/user/outputpath')
?>
```

If i make a change in the script it is not working in browser

```
<?php
&cmd = system('python script.py /home/user/filename.rar /home/user/outputpath')
?>
```

But both is working perfectly from terminal

Can any one help me on this..

Comment: php scripts don't run in the browser. Try to rephrase your question.

Comment: What do you mean by not working in browser ? Blank page ? If so, enable error reporting

Comment: Not shpwing any error its stops execution in between

Comment: I am also facing such issue in php

Comment: turn on your error reporting? What does your error log tell you?